# How to perform batching when requesting records from route53 hosted zone to retrieve all the records

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, groovy, amazon-route53

My hosted zone has over 2500 records. I wrote java code that retrieves the resource records from a specified hosted zone using ListResourceRecordSetsRequest. However, it is only listing 300 records at max. How can I perform batching so I can retrieve all 2500 records?

```
ListResourceRecordSetsRequest request = ListResourceRecordSetsRequest.builder()
                .hostedZoneId(hostedZone.id())
                .maxItems("1000")
                .build() as ListResourceRecordSetsRequest
        ListResourceRecordSetsResponse listResourceRecordSets = route53Client.listResourceRecordSets(request);
        List<ResourceRecordSet> records = listResourceRecordSets.resourceRecordSets();
        return records
```

The code above is what I use and it returns 300 records at best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following snippet to iterate through all records.

```
final ListResourceRecordSetsRequest listRecordSetRequest = new ListResourceRecordSetsRequest().
                withHostedZoneId(hostedZone.getId());
ListResourceRecordSetsResult listRecordSetResult;
final List<ResourceRecordSet> resourceRecordSets = new ArrayList<>();
do {
      listRecordSetResult = route53.listResourceRecordSets(listRecordSetRequest);
      resourceRecordSets.addAll(listRecordSetResult.getResourceRecordSets());
            listRecordSetRequest.setStartRecordIdentifier(listRecordSetResult.getNextRecordIdentifier());
} while (listRecordSetResult.isTruncated());
```